# Average triangles in DirectX 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

So I basically want to check some information for my project.
I have GTX 460 video card. I wrote DX10 program with 20k triangles printed on the screen and now I get 28 FPS in Release build. All those triangles call DrawIndexed inside them so this is ofcourse an overhead in calling so much draws.

But anyway, I would like to know: how much triangles could I draw on the screen with those capabilities and at which FPS? I think 20k triangles is not even nearly enough to load some good models on game scene.

Sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are creating a single draw call per triangle primitive, this is very bad, hence the horrid FPS, you should aim to draw as many triangles as possible per draw call, this can be done in a few ways:

- Profile your code, both nVidia and AMD have free to to you you find why your code is slow, allowing you to focus where it really matters, so use them.
- Index buffers & triangle strips to reduce bandwidth
- Grouping of verts by material type/state/texture to improve batching
- Instancing of primitive groups: draw multiple models/meshs in one call
- Remove as much redundant state change (setting of shaders, textures, buffers, paramters) as possible, this goes hand-in-hand with the group mentioned earlier

The DX SDK will have examples of implementing each of these. The exact amount for triangles you can draw and a decent FPS(either 30 or 60 if you want vsync) varies greatly depending on the complexity of shading the triangles, however, if draw most simply, you should be able to push a few million with ease.

I would recommend taking a good look at the innards of an open source DX11 (not many DX10 projects exists, but the API is almost identical) engine, such as [heiroglyph 3](http://hieroglyph3.codeplex.com/), and going through the SDK tutorials.

There are also quite a few presentations on increasing performance with DX10, but profile your code before diving into the suggestions full-on, here are a few from the hardware vendors themselves (color coded hints for nVidia vs AMD hardware):

- [GDC '08](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2008/GDC/GDC08-D3DDay-Performance.pdf)
- [GDC '09](http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/The%20A%20to%20Z%20of%20DX10%20Performance.pps)